# Differences in Spearman coefficient between R and pandas

Tags: r, correlation, python, spearman-rho

I've noticed a small difference between pandas and R with regards to how they calculate Spearman coefficients. It seems as if some rounding occurs. I see no such difference when calculating Kendall or Pearson. Does anyone know what might cause this? A simple example is provided below illustrating the differences.

```
#------------  R CODE --------------
x <- seq(-1,1,length=100)
y <- x^2

( cor(cbind(x,y), method="spearman") )
( cor(cbind(x,y), method="kendall") )

#------------  OUTPUT FROM R -------------
> ( cor(cbind(x,y), method="spearman") )
           x          y
x 1.00000000 0.01310547
y 0.01310547 1.00000000
> ( cor(cbind(x,y), method="kendall") )
            x           y
x 1.000000000 0.009296686
y 0.009296686 1.000000000

#------ PYTHON --------------
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-1,1,100)
y = x**2

df = pd.DataFrame({"x":x, "y":y})

print(df.corr(method="spearman"))

print(df.corr(method="kendall"))

#--------  OUTPUT FROM PYTHON --------------
   x  y
x  1  0
y  0  1
          x         y
x  1.000000  0.009297
y  0.009297  1.000000
```

Comment: try to identify the smallest, simplest possible example that shows a difference (e.g. does it happen when there are exactly 3 values in x and y?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This almost certainly has to do with how the 2 program determine ties. The way you have constructed your data, y[i] and y[100 - i + 1] should be equal(using R indexing), but because of the way that computers handle floating point numbers, they are not. For example, in R:

```
> y[1] == [100]
[1] TRUE
> y[2] == y[99]
[1] FALSE
> y[2] - y[99]
[1] -2.220446e-16
```

In digging through the pandas code, it appears they are using a relative tolerance of 1e-7 to determine if 2 floating point numbers differ (see function float64_are_diff [in this file](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/algos.pyx) . So, in the pandas implementation, these elements are tied.

Note that if you do a similar example in R using integers, then it arrives at the same answer as pandas:

```
> x <- seq(-50,50,length=101)
> y <- x^2
> cor(x,y, method="spearman")
[1] 0
```